# How to check if a TMS WEB Core Website is run on a mobile or desktop?

Tags: delphi, tms, tms-web-core

I want to know whether the user is using the website from a desktop or a mobile so that I can adjust my UI according to the person's device (desktop or mobile).

How can I check this in TMS WEB Core using Delphi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways you can do this, but here are three of the ways that I found:

## Application.IsMobile

You can use the `Application.IsMobile` function to check if it's a mobile or desktop device. This function will literally just return a boolean that says `True` or `False` depending on whether it's a mobile or not:

```
if Application.IsMobile then
  ShowMessage('This is a mobile device')
else
  ShowMessage('This is not a mobile device');
```

This is also the recommended method to check if it's a mobile device or desktop device.

## Custom Function using the browser's window width

You could write your own `IsMobile` function that uses the browser's window width.

This isn't 100% accurate as it doesn't check if it's actually a mobile device or not, but rather assumes it's a mobile device if the width is very small. This is fairly common practice in websites using CSS Media Queries.

```
function CheckMobile(): Boolean;
begin
  Result := window.outerWidth < 800;
end;
```

You can change the "800" to whatever you want "mobile" to be, and then you can use it like this:

```
if CheckMobile then
  ShowMessage('This is a mobile device')
else
  ShowMessage('This is not a mobile device');
```

## Using the Form's Width

This is very similar to using the browser's window width, but here you're using the form's width. So assuming your form's name is `Form1`, then you can do:

```
if (Form1.Width < 800) then
  ShowMessage('This is a mobile device')
else
  ShowMessage('This is not a mobile device');
```

Comment: Is this a joke? A browser window doesn't have to be maximized, let alone its child windows - using my netbook is then assumed to be "_mobile_". You could have also [linked to the DevGuide page 116](https://download.tmssoftware.com/download/manuals/TMSWEBCoreDevGuide.pdf).

Comment: I would use Application.IsMobile as it does more than check width.